# Use variables in SPEC file of PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to use the variable `%appdata%` in the `runtime_tmpdir` part of my PyInstaller SPEC file like that:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='oky',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir="%appdata%\\MyFolder",
          console=False )
```

But I think that it doesn't understand `%appdata%`, is there's any way to use the variables inside the SPEC file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set your windows environment like this:

```
runtime_tmpdir=os.environ['appdata']+"\\MyFolder",
```